# transition:rotate is not working in Firefox

Tags: css

This is my code and transform is working in chrome browser but in firefox it is not working.

```css
.delete-white a:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 15px;
    left: 6px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
}
.delete-white a:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 5px;
    left: 1px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
}
```

Comment: Transitions are not transforms. `transition: rotate(...)` is not going to work but `transform: rotate(...)` will.

Answer (score 3):

Two notes

1. You need to have `content` to `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements
2. You have forgotten the unprefixed version: `transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);`

Comment: I am using content but this is not solving my problem                     .delete-white:before, .delete-white:after, .delete-white a:before, .delete-white a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}

Comment: @VikashAnand, what does not work ? This example http://jsfiddle.net/Nv22b/1/ seems to work just fine..

Answer (score 3):

Add this rule to element: "display: inline-block;"

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the standard, non-prefixed version (i.e. `transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);`) as the final definition in your list of transforms. The `-moz` one is deprecated, as will/should be the other ones in time. [See the MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I have added this  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); but still i am facing issue.

Comment: .delete-white:before, .delete-white:after, .delete-white a:before, .delete-white a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
}

.delete-white a:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 15px;
    left: 6px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1); 
}

Comment: Sorry, I mean a Fiddle or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/) including the relevant HTML, so that we can see exactly what is going on. From the looks of that, though, you should try putting a space in the content (i.e. `content: " ";`). That might do the trick.